# How I can select random row in array?

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm

I've got project for genetic algorithm. I make random array with my code. 
I need your help for random two row selection. If you can please give me example code because I try too many times but I can't find the solution.

Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 20 

void init(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int sum[SIZE]);
void dump(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int sum[SIZE]);

int main()
{
  int a[SIZE][SIZE]; 
  int sum[SIZE]; 
  init(a, sum);
  dump(a, sum);
  return 0;
}

void init(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int sum[SIZE])
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i,j;
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
  {
    sum[i] = 0;
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j)
    {
      a[i][j] = rand() % 2;
      sum[i] += a[i][j];
    }
  }
}
void dump(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int sum[SIZE])
{
  int i,j;
  for (i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
  {
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j)
      printf("% 2d", a[i][j]);
    printf(" sum = %d\n", sum[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What question are you are asking? Do you want to print two different rows? Where have you tried to do that?

Comment: This code give me 20 rows. I need select two random rows but I can't write this code block.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? The problem is not shown in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use random function -  rand()

if you use `rand()% RAND_MAX`
rand() will generate random number from 0 to RAND_MAX-1,
i.e rand()%100 will generate random number from 0 to 99.

Random number between minimum and maximum can be generated by:

```
minimum + (rand() % (maximum – minimum + 1));
```

But, whenever you need to generate sequence of random number you should use srand() function.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I don't need generate new sequence. I need to choose two of my previous series, in my code I generated. But I don't know how I can pick two row.